# O que eu criar no blender, posso vender?

Tags: unity3d, jogos

O que eu criar no blender, posso vender ou usar sem me preocupar com licenças?(exemplo cria modelos, animações, videos e usar no Unity 3D)

Comment: De um modo geral, os **dados** produzidos por um programa não têm relação nenhuma com esse programa (ex.: se você escrever um texto usando o Word, os direitos autorais dele não vão pra Microsoft). Dessa forma, o que você criar no Blender é seu, independentemente dele ser software livre, gratuito, etc (modelos criados no Maya também seriam seus). Podem existir exceções, uma que conheço é quando o "dado" incorpora parte do código em si próprio - caracterizando uma cópia. Da mesma forma, se você usou um modelo de outra pessoa como base pro que você criou, pode precisar de licença dessa pessoa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O blender é um software open source então tudo que você produzir nele poderá ser comercializado sem problemas não tem nenhum tipo de licença paga, já o unity se for utilizado a ativação gratuita não sendo o pro crackeado também, acredito que seja como visual studio express por ter recursos que o pro não tem você pode produzir e distribuir.